# edit jquery dt response before render

Tags: datatables

I have serverside pagination datatable with defination below, it works fine but the thing is;one of the field contains too long so I need to set a details button instead of it, when its clicked pop up showns up and view the data of descripotion.

I tried add `success:function(aaData){..}` to ajax but it brokes the datatable any suggestion? and I dont want to edit tho model in controller I have data in browser so I want to handle this here..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#dtBooks').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "filter": false,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetBooks", "Home")",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"

            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "Title", "name": "Title", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Publisher", "name": "Publisher", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Description", "name": "Description", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "Authors", "name": "Authors", "autoWidth": true },
            ]
    });
    });
```

here is the model defination contorller response list of this model to datatable.

```
public class Book 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string[] Authors { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option to manipulate the data returned from the server.

For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
      for ( var i=0, ien=json.data.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
        json.data[i][0] = '<a href="/message/'+json.data[i][0]+'>View message</a>';
      }
      return json.data;
    }
  }
});
```